# Listing only folders in directory

Tags: c++, posix

I want to list folders in a directory in C++, ideally in a portable (working in the major Operating Systems) way. I tried using POSIX, and it works correctly, but how can i identify whether the found item is a folder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the C++17 [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_directories(const std::string& s)
{
    std::vector<std::string> r;
    for(auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(s))
        if (p.is_directory())
            r.push_back(p.path().string());
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I believe that since this is more portable way and still doesn't use any external libraries, it deserves more to be an accepted answer now.

Comment: I get Segmentation faults once I cross the local application path. Eg. List the directories of /home/$USER. is this just me or this filesystem very unstable on my system?

Comment: I believe `p.status().type() == std::filesystem::file_type::directory` can be replaced with `p.is_directory()`, unless there are subtle differences I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 28):

You could use `opendir()` and `readdir()` to list directories and subdirectories. The following example prints all subdirectories inside the current path:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* PATH = ".";

    DIR *dir = opendir(PATH);

    struct dirent *entry = readdir(dir);

    while (entry != NULL)
    {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
            printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);

        entry = readdir(dir);
    }

    closedir(dir);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can select only folders by using these functions. I have added an example to show you how.

Comment: [Error] 'struct dirent' has no member named 'd_type' . why do I get this error ?

Comment: Thanks for this great anwser. I'm using linux and I want to how to list linked directories, please.

Comment: @Faridzs See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430337/1279291

Comment: @andreasdr wow, that comment was written around 5 years ago :)) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 10):

Here follows a (slightly modified) quote from the [boost filesystem documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm#tutorial) to show you how it can be done:

```
void iterate_over_directories( const path & dir_path )         // in this directory,
{
  if ( exists( dir_path ) ) 
  {
    directory_iterator end_itr; // default construction yields past-the-end
    for ( directory_iterator itr( dir_path );
          itr != end_itr;
          ++itr )
    {
      if ( is_directory(itr->status()) )
      {
        //... here you have a directory
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the directory name in form of a string?

Comment: Note that `boost::filesystem` needs to be built. It is not headers-only.

Answer (score 5):

Look up the `stat` function. [Here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) is a description. Some sample code:

```
struct stat st;
const char *dirname = "dir_name";
if( stat( dirname, &st ) == 0 && S_ISDIR( st.st_mode ) ) {
    // "dir_name" is a subdirectory of the current directory
} else {
    // "dir_name" doesn't exist or isn't a directory
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel compelled to mention [PhysFS](http://icculus.org/physfs/).  I just integrated it into my own project.  It provides true cross-platform (Mac / Linux / PC) file operations and can even unpack various archive definitions such as zip, 7zip, pak, and so on.  It has a few functions ([PHYSFS_isDirectory](http://icculus.org/physfs/docs/html/physfs_8h.html#a5877fcafb72dca892c1c2465292eef47), [PHYSFS_enumerateFiles](http://icculus.org/physfs/docs/html/physfs_8h.html#a0f4ae950c2dae0735a91263ddd20fbf4)) which can determine what you are asking for as well.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, you can use _findfirst() and _findnext() to iterate through the contents of a directory, and then use CreateFile() and GetFileInformationByHandle() to determine whether a particular entry is a directory or a folder.  (Yes, CreateFile(), with the appropriate arguments, to examine an existing file.  Ain't life grand?)

For reference, some classes where I implemented code that uses those calls can be seen [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/Directory.cpp) and [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/FilePathInfo.cpp)

Comment: Links are dead. An example code would be helpful.

Comment: @Burak I fixed the links.