# I would like to obtain time (ctime(..)?) of a file in host language

Tags: c, linux, io, systems-programming, ctime

I have a function like this:

```
void ft_display_time(struct timespec ttime)
{
    char *time_long;
    
    time_long = ctime(&ttime.tv_sec);
    if (time_long)
    {
        ft_printf("%.3s ", time_long + 4);
        ft_printf("%.2s ", time_long + 8);
        ft_printf("%.5s ", time_long + 11);
    }
    else
        ft_putstr("             ");
}
```

I'm trying get an output like `ls -l` does. But `ctime(const time_t *clock)` will return a string in english (so months are displayed like "Dec" "Jan" "Aug" ...), while `ls -l` outputs months in the host language format (for example french).

Example:

```
./myprog --long file
-rw-r--r--  1 lotolo  staff   0 Sep 17 19:55 c

/bin/ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 lotolo  staff   0 17 Set 19:55 c
```

How could I have the output in host language format?

For instance, `ttime` is equal to `stat.st_atimespec` or `stat.st_mtimespec` returned by `stat(filename, &stat)` or `lstat(filename, &stat)`
I know I will have to change most of my `ft_display_time()` funtion, but I would like to know if there is any way of getting `ctime()` output in the right language.

Comment: Did you try setting the locale using `setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL)` before using the string display routines?

Comment: Yes! I tried but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scusa, but *I* don't know a way to do this by using another `ctime()`-like function only. If I were you though, I would try a different approach:

Execute `/bin/ls` with [execv()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv), just like in  [How to list first level directories only in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429803/how-to-list-first-level-directories-only-in-c) For maximum pleasure, combine it with [Redirecting exec output to a buffer or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file).

---

If you want to do a universal change, then you could use what Petesh said:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL)
```

which, quoting the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/),:

> Sets locale information to be used by the current program, either changing the entire locale or portions of it.

Comment: I don't get the connection between my answer and the firsts two refs... I must be tired. Anyway I get setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), i've tested it but It still output in english... I'm diggin' it

Comment: @LotoLo since `ls` gives you what you want, you could execute that instead of `ctime()`. As for `setlocale()`, I can't think of anything else... :/